# TypeInitializationException while loading images

Tags: c#, wpf, image

**What I want to do:**

I want to see an Image in WPF.

**Problem:**

When I try to load the Image I get a `TypeInitializationException`.

**What I tried to solve this problem:**

I implemented a `try-catch`. If the first `Image` (the `Image` I actually want to have) throws a `TypeInitializationException` I will see another `Image` (just for testing). The second `Image` (from the `catch` block) is visible but the `Image` I want to see isn't. Both `Image`s have the property `"embedded Resource"`. Both `Image`s are in the same `namespace` (`Travelagency.Ressources`) but in different subdirectories (`Menu` and `TravelDataFilterMenuIcons`).

C# Code:

`TravelDataFilterVM.cs`

```
MenuEntry money = null;
try
{
    money = new MenuEntry(Guid.NewGuid(), Travelagency.Ressources.TravelDataFilterMenuIcons.TravelDataFilterMenuIcon.Euro);
}
catch(TypeInitializationException ex)
{
    money = new MenuEntry(Guid.NewGuid(), Travelagency.Ressources.Menu.MenuIcon.MenuImage);
}
```

`TravelDataFilterMenuIcon.cs` (doesn't work)

```
public static readonly BitmapImage Euro = ImageLoader.LoadImageAsBitmap("Travelagency.Ressources.TravelDataFilterMenuIcons.euro.png");
```

`Menu.cs` (does work)

```
public static readonly BitmapImage MenuImage = ImageLoader.LoadImageAsBitmap("Travelagency.Ressources.Menu.menu5.png");
```

**edit**

I found out that the every `Image` is loadable from `Menu.cs` but no `Image` is loadable from `TravelDataFilterVM.cs`. The problem is not the path or something with the `Image` it's the `class`. So here are both `classes`:

`TravelDataFilterVM.cs` (doesn't work)

```
using System.Windows.Media.Imaging;

namespace Travelagency.Ressources.TravelDataFilterMenuIcons
{
    public class TravelDataFilterMenuIcon
    {
        private TravelDataFilterMenuIcon() { }

        public static readonly BitmapImage Euro = ImageLoader.LoadImageAsBitmap("Travelagency.Ressources.TravelDataFilterMenuIcons.euro.png");
        public static readonly BitmapImage Fuenfzigeuro = ImageLoader.LoadImageAsBitmap("Travelagency.Ressources.TravelDataFilterMenuIcons.fuenfzigeuro.png");
        public static readonly BitmapImage Hunderteuro = ImageLoader.LoadImageAsBitmap("Travelagency.Ressources.TravelDataFilterMenuIcons.hunderteuro.png");
    }
}
```

`Menu.cs` (does work)

```
using System.Windows.Media.Imaging;

namespace Travelagency.Ressources.Menu
{
    public class MenuIcon
    {
        private MenuIcon() { }

        public static readonly byte[] MENU = ImageLoader.LoadImageAsByteArray("Travelagency.Ressources.Menu.menu5.png");
        public static readonly BitmapImage MenuImage = ImageLoader.LoadImageAsBitmap("Travelagency.Ressources.Menu.menu5.png");
    }
}
```

Comment: And the exception is...? (I note that the word "Resources" is mis-spelled in both cases by the way - and is your menu image really "Menu.menu5.png"?

Comment: Well the first Image gets a TypeInitializationException that's why the second Image is always loaded. And Yeah it's mis-spelled and it's menu5.png due to some testing with different classes/images.

Comment: You have different paths `Travelagency.Ressources.TravelDataFilterMenuIcons.euro.png` vs `Travelagency.Ressources.Menu.menu5.png`. What happens if you try to load `Travelagency.Ressources.TravelDataFilterMenuIcons.euro.png` in Menu?

Comment: This code in `Menu.cs` does work: `public static readonly BitmapImage Euro = ImageLoader.LoadImageAsBitmap("Travelagency.Ressources.TravelDataFilterMenuIcons.euro.png");`

Answer (score -1):

Now it works! I have no idea why. I changed nothing. I didn't even restarted anything.